# GNSS-SDR on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, gps, uhd

I know the answer might be negative, but is there any way to run Gnss-Sdr on Windows Instead of Linux/Mac OS?
I Use it on Linux Already But I have just wondered if it can be done.
only related answers please.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. I'm just doing this. The problem is that some code fragments are written under Linux. The build system and library search methods are also under it. For the first time, I had to cut TCP data transfer and heavily correct some CMake files. I build it with the help MSYS2 under MinGW. The biggest problem is linking files. At this stage, I build most of the individual components. It was also required to manually build all the libraries. With my little experience in porting programs from system to system, it was hard